# Why my React application with Table component doesn't display all of the records?

Tags: reactjs, datatable, blueprint

Why my React application with Table component from [Blueprintjs](https://blueprintjs.com/docs/#table), doesn't display all of the records? It only displays <= 201 records

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import {Table, Column, Cell} from '@blueprintjs/table';
    import "@blueprintjs/table/lib/css/table.css"   
    
    export default class App extends Component{
        public render() {
            return (
                    <Table numRows={500} enableGhostCells = {true}>
                        <Column key={1} name = {"0"} cellRenderer={this.ColumnHeaderCellRenderer}/>
                    </Table>
            )
        }
    
        ColumnHeaderCellRenderer = (rowIndex, columnIndex) => {
            return <Cell>{(rowIndex*columnIndex).toString()}</Cell>
        }
    }
```

Comment: How many records are there in the db or table?

Comment: there are around 700 records in the dataset that i use. But i dont think it is really matters, because if there are only 202 records in the dataset it will only displays me 201 record.

Comment: No errors in the JS console, or React console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is caused by incorrect css.
https://github.com/palantir/blueprint/issues/1807